# Get String from VBA DataObject object after GetText

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to do some string manipulation (trim and split) with text data received from a TextBox in UserForm Excel Visual Basic VBA. But I can't get the String / text data obtained from user clipboard stored in the Microsoft Form 2.0 DataObject.

I tried
    `Dim s As String = CType(strPaste, String)`
but it says expected end of statement.

If I only do 
    `s = CType(strPaste, String)`
then it's a syntax error.

I've also poked around the Microsoft Forms documentation but there is no list of methods associated with DataObject.

This is what I have.

```
Dim dataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set dataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
dataObj.GetFromClipboard
strPaste = dataObj.GetText()
```

the Variant Type of `strPaste` is 0, which is an object. I'd like it to be a String.

Comment: That VB.NET not VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use early binding, you can see the methods in the Object Browser.

Here are some examples of putting stuff onto the clipboard, and reading from it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim dataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim getStr As String
    Const putStr As String = "This went to the clipboard"

    Set dataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    dataObj.SetText putStr
    dataObj.PutInClipboard

    dataObj.GetFromClipboard
    getStr = dataObj.GetText

    MsgBox getStr
End Sub
```

And something placed on the clipboard by an ordinary copy operation:

```
Sub foo2()
    Dim dataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim R As Range
    Dim getStr As String

Set R = Cells(1, 1)
With R
    .Value = "abcxyz^123"
    .Copy
End With

Set dataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

dataObj.GetFromClipboard
getStr = dataObj.GetText

MsgBox getStr
End Sub
```

You may also find [Microsoft Forms Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/reference-microsoft-forms) of value, and also the link to the Examples which shows some other examples of using these methods, and interacting with a text box.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I should use dataObj.GetText instead of dataObj.GetText()!